# Which relationship makes more sense

Tags: sql, orm, rdbms

I have two entities in question:

1. Work Order
2. Warranty

A warranty is performed on a work order. In the system we are replacing this relationship was achieved by adding the required "warranty" information to the work order table itself, and a "warranty tracking id" was added to the table. Problem is only about 3% of work orders are ever returned as warranty so most records had 6 or 7 fields which were never used.

When re-designing the database, we opted for two tables (entities) so the relationships now look like:

```
workorder:
ID, SerialNumber, ModelNumber, PartNumber, ...

warranty:
ID, WorkOrderId1, WorkOrderId2, Description, RepairCost, ....
```

Several years later and I find myself re-designing the database again...this time however, I consider using a relationship like this:

```
workorder:
ID, SerialNumber, ModelNumber, PartNumber, ...

warranty:
ID, Description, RepairCost, ....

workorder_warranty:
ID, WorkOrderId1, WorkOrderId2
```

Introducing the junction table workorder_warranty as a way of expressing the rather odd 1:1 relationship and entity linking necessary to meet user requirements.

A workorder will only ever have ONE warranty possibly claimed, so this model (typically reserved for n:m relationships) seems odd to me...

The fact the junction table is serving to link two entities of a similar type, as opposed to two different entities is what is causing me some grievances here.

- Alex

Comment: So the two table design makes more sense to you eh? I have to say I feel the same...the requirement for 1:m should never be an issue...it should always be a 1:1 relatiosnhsip between child and parent (so to speak)

Answer (score 0):

The current db layout is the best model whatsoever to represent such a 1:1 relation. The only point I see in moving to your new model would be to make sure this is future-proof if ever the relationship changes to 1-to-many. In this case your code would already be ready...